# How can I adjust a photo into a div respecting the div height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was reading some answered questions in here, but I still have the problem, I can't "re-adjust" an image inside a div, the image doesn't respect the containing height of the div, and also I cant make the part of the image that I want show on it, this is what I mean:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<section id="about">
   <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <div class="row content">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section id="img">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row content">
      <div id="imgcont">
         <div id="header">
            <div class="title">
               <h1>Title in image centered</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row content text-center">
      <h1>More content, same section </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</section>
<section id="howto">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row content">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: white;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


.row.content {
    min-height: 450px
}


#about {
    background-color: red;
}

#img {
    background-color: gray;
    height 100%;
}

#howto {
    background-color: #003300;
}

#imgcont {
    height: 50%;
}

#header {
    background: url(http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/162/6155406-mountain-images.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://codepen.io/elunap/pen/ZaXKKK

I have 3 sections in which I have different content, on the second section I want to adjust the image to appear like that, without overlapping the image and the top section.

This is my goal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep2GT.jpg

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#header {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

To

```
#header {
    height: 50%;
}
```

Updated sample: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYoRNq